# Migrating PL/SQL Web Toolkit web app from Apache/mod_plsql to Tomcat/ORDS causes issues with logging out of web app

Tags: oracle, tomcat8, mod-plsql

My PL/SQL Web Toolkit application is having issues logging out.  The Apache/mod_plsql configuration had a "logmeoff" function that I could use to log out when using Apache HTTP.  But now that I migrated to Tomcat/ORDS, the "logmeoff" function does not exist and I have not found a replacement (or method) to logout.  Any ideas?

The issue is that I can never log out of the web application.  And there are no errors reported.
The session stays active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Release Notes of ORDS (since v18)

*Support For mod_plsql logmeoff*

*The mod_plsql logmeoff mechanism is not supported reliably by modern browsers and it is not provided by ORDS. The only way to end a HTTP Basic Authentication session is to close the Browser.*

Comment: Or rewrite your app to make REST API calls instead, those are by definition, Stateless. Each and every call is a seff-contained transaction.